# Can not render different results with conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to check if the user has a username to allow him to upload images otherwise i want to ask the user to login but i try to do that this error appears :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of null

App
C:/Users/User/Desktop/try-react/new-app/src/App.js:91
```

this it the code which causes the error:

```html
return (
    <div className="app">
 
        {user.displayName  ? <ImageUpload  username={user.displayName} /> : <h3>login</h3>}
```

Comment: the App.js: 91 line of code is:  { <div className="app">}

Comment: Error message is pretty self-explanatory, i.e. `user` is `null`. Reason could be the initial render of the component before `user` has a value. Make sure `user` is not `null` before accessing its `.displayName` property.

Answer (score 1):

Your user has null value. Use this for null check

```
{user ? <ImageUpload  username={user?.displayName} /> : <h3>login</h3>}
```

Comment: Since you are checking if `user` is truthy or not, there's no need for optional-chaining to access `.displayName` property.

Comment: this is give you an extra check for the cases when you don't have user as an object.